# Error in creating mofa object when doing multi-omics factor analysis in r

Tags: r, bioinformatics, data-analysis

I am doing multi-omics factor analysis in r and after importing csv file of my data and started to make mofa object and found that message "Error in create_mofa_from_df(microbiome) : all(colnames(df) %in% (c("sample", "feature", "value", "group", .... is not TRUE ".

Here's the code I'm using:

```r
MOFAobject_untrained <- create_mofa_from_df(microbiome)
```

Comment: 1) Are you using the [MOFA2](https://biofam.github.io/MOFA2/index.html) package for doing this analysis? 2) Can you provide the column names of your dataframe? 3) Can you provide the code that triggers the error?

Comment: 1- No, I will try MOFA2  

3- MOFAobject_untrained <- create_mofa_from_df(microbiome)

Comment: 2- [1] "X"                         "OTU"                      
 [3] "Sample"                    "Abundance"                
 [5] "TimeStart"                 "SampleNo"                 
 [7] "SampleNo.1"                "PatientDesc"              
 [9] "BarcodeSequence"           "LinkerPrimerSequence"     
[11] "forward.absolute.filepath" "reverse.absolute.filepath"
[13] "HealthState"               "TimePoint"

Comment: [15] "Age"                       "Gender"                   
[17] "Smoking"                   "Hypertension"             
[19] "Diabetes"                  "Heart.Failure"            
[21] "Kidney.Disease"            "Chest.Disease"            
[23] "Gastro.Disease"            "GyNocological.Disease"    
[25] "HCV"                       "PCR"                      
[27] "ALT"                       "AST"

Comment: [29] "Albumine"                  "Bilirubin.Total"          
[31] "Bilirubin.Direct"          "Creatinine"               
[33] "P.T"                       "Hb.."                     
[35] "Fast..Glucose"             "Kingdom"                  
[37] "Phylum"                    "Class"                    
[39] "Order"                     "Family"                   
[41] "Genus"                     "Species"

Comment: What package are you using to do this analysis, then?

Comment: I revised my package I am already using MOFA2 Package

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for how to use the `create_mofa_from_df()` function? https://rdrr.io/github/bioFAM/MOFA2/man/create_mofa_from_df.html

Comment: @NickODell yes and this is the result "Error in create_mofa_from_df(microbiome, extract_metadata = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (extract_metadata = TRUE)"

Comment: when writing ?create_mofa_from_df 
i found this 
Method to create a MOFA object from a data.frame object

Usage
create_mofa_from_df(df)
Arguments
df 
data.frame object with at most 5 columns: sample, group, feature, view, value. The group column (optional) indicates the group of each sample when using the multi-group framework. The view column (optional) indicates the view of each feature when having multi-view data.

Comment: is that means that columns should be 5 column only ?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: @NickODell after reduction of columns to "feature" "sample"  "value"   "time"    "group"  i found result : "Error in create_mofa_from_df(new_microbiome) : all(colnames(df) %in% (c("sample", "feature", "value", "group", .... is not TRUE"

Comment: @NickODell i did it finally after rearrangement of columns as the code. It is finally working. Thanks for your time ^^

Comment: Glad to help. Do you mind adding an answer to the question, summarizing how you fixed it? It will be helpful to the next person to have this problem.

Comment: Ok I will summarize it after training the whole model to collect the whole experience

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: all i did is subsetting the columns in the error c("sample", "feature", "value", "group") 
with the same arrangement,  and the code already run. but at the end, I didn't use the MOFA as my data was not enough to be analysed